# ¿Cual es la mejor práctica para añadir objetos con relaciones en Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, code-first

Recientemente creé un proyecto Web Api en DotNetCore 3.1 e implementé **Entity Framework Core** usando **Code-First**. Cada uno de mis modelos se refiere a otros como este:

```
public class Condominium
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public int Levels { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CondominiumType CondominiumType { get; set; }
}
```

Como pueden ver en este ejemplo me refiero a la clase Address y CondominiumType sin escribir un Id de referencia. Entity Framework me creara las correspondiente claves foráneas cuando las migraciones sean ejecutadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto funciona perfectamente bien cuando quiero agregar un nuevo Condominium con una nueva Address pero estoy enfrentando un problema cuando quiero agregar una Address **existente** o un condominiumType

Cuando le paso un objeto al contexto con un Id que ya fue agregado a la base de datos el programa me dispara una excepción porque estoy violando la cláusula Unique de la tabla.

Yo se que puedo solucionar este problema simplemente agregando propiedades de referencia a los otros objetos:

```
    public class Condominium
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public int Levels { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CondominiumTypeId { get; set; }
    public CondominiumType CondominiumType { get; set; }

}
```

Sin embargo me pregunto cual es la manera apropiada de resolver esta clase de situaciones y si es posible agregar un objeto existente sin tener que reescribir todas mis clases

Answer (score 0):

En la POO (programación orientada a objetos) existe un concepto: la `composición de objetos`, que es el mecanismo en el cual una clase se construye a partir de otros objetos de igual o distinto tipo, pudiéndolos combinar para obtener la funcionalidad deseada.

Esto aplicado en tu ejemplo vendría a ser representada por la clase `Condominium` que se está compuesta de otros objetos: del objeto `Address` y el objeto `CondominiumType`.

Ahora bien, si estás usando EntityFramework y CodeFirst para representar las clases dentro de tu dominio, es necesario que conozcas el concepto de:

> Anotaciones: que en c# y CodeFirst se conocen como `DataAnnotations`

que pueden ser utilizadas a nivel de las propiedades dentro de una clase, o a nivel de la clase. Se utilizan para seguir las convenciones de Entity Framework y en otros casos, las que no siguen las convenciones tienen posibilidad de agregar configuraciones a las clases para proporcionar a Entity Framework la información necesaria a través de estas anotaciones.

Existen 2 anotaciones que te pueden ayudar específicamente con tu objetivo:

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Son clases que se usan a nivel de `using`, la primera se usa para adicionar restricciones de validación, como ser requerimiento de llenado de campos, restricciones de longitud entre otras. Y la segunda proporciona una manera de describir las configuraciones de forma imperativa, en el código del esquema de la base de datos como ser las llaves foráneas.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Condominium
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //define llaves foráneas
    // (dentro va el nombre de la clase modelo referenciada)
    [ForeignKey("Address")] 
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public int Levels { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)] //Valida que la longitud máxima sea de 100
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]//Define al campo como requerido
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CondominiumType ")]
    public int CondominiumTypeId { get; set; }

    public CondominiumType CondominiumType { get; set; }

}
```

Y es básicamente eso, existen más anotaciones que se pueden utilizar;
para ello te dejo este enlace:

[DataAnnotacions en Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations)

Lo ideal sería que construyas tu dominio o base de datos a través de migraciones, ya que estás usando CodeFirst, para que cuando publiques tu sitio en producción se construya a través de tus clases, ya que además de tener un histórico de cambios, puedas en caso de que requieras deshacer los últimos cambios en tu base de datos y siempre se mantengan sincronizadas tus clases y las tablas en tu base de datos.